# Dynamically replace text in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to create a routine that replaces a variable number of values within a given string. For example, if I have a base text in the spreadsheet of:

“Your vehicle selection of {0} indicates you should have between {1} and {2} tires. However, you have entered {3} tires for this vehicle. Please update the record accordingly.”

I would like to replace the tokens with either a constant value from the application or some other variable a user entered. I’m trying to create a routine with a signature such as the following, where RowID is the row in the spreadsheet where the base text is located and ReplacementValues is an array of n number of variables:

```
Sub ShowMsg(ByVal RowID As Integer, Optional ByVal ReplacementValues As Variant)
```

I can’t figure out how to loop through the text and replace each token without repeating the entire text of the base message in each iteration. If possible I would like to keep the routine fairly generic and not specific to Excel in case I need to move the application to a database at some point later.

Hope I have explained this sufficiently; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can;

```
Sub ShowMsg(ByVal RowID As Integer, Optional ReplacementValues As Variant)
Dim data As String, i As Long
If Not IsMissing(ReplacementValues) Then
    data = Range("A" & RowID).Value
    For i = 0 To UBound(ReplacementValues)
        data = Replace(data, "{" & i & "}", ReplacementValues(i))
    Next
    msgbox data
End If
End Sub
```

called with;

```
Dim a() As Variant: a = Array("aa", "bb", "cc")
ShowMsg 8, a
```

Or an alternative:

```
Sub ShowMsg(ByVal RowID As Integer, ParamArray ReplacementValues() As Variant)
Dim data As String, i As Long
If Not IsMissing(ReplacementValues) Then
    data = Range("A" & RowID).Value
    If IsArray(ReplacementValues(0)) Then ReplacementValues = ReplacementValues(0)
    For i = 0 To UBound(ReplacementValues)
        data = Replace(data, "{" & i & "}", ReplacementValues(i))
    Next
    msgbox data
End If
End Sub
```

which can be called in the same way or additionally with ordinal arguments;

```
ShowMsg 8, "aa", "bb", "cc"
```

Answer (score 1):

First change your base string to something like this

```
BaseString = "Your vehicle selection of {VEHSEL} indicates you should have " & _
             "between {nTYRE1} and {nTYRE2} tires. However, you have entered " & _
             "{nTotTYRE} tires for this vehicle. Please update the record " & _
             "accordingly."
```

If you notice now that you have specific **Keywords** like

```
VEHSEL - Vehicle Selection
nTYRE1 - Lowest selection of tires
nTYRE2 - Highest selection of tires
nTotTYRE - Total tires selected
```

Once you pick up the values from the spreadhseet, simply use `REPLACE` to replace the above **Keywords** with the relevant values

So your code will look like

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim lVSell As Long, lT1  As Long, lT2  As Long, ltotT As Long
    Dim lRowID As Long

    lRowID = 5

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lVSell = .Range("A" & lRowID).Value
        lT1 = .Range("B" & lRowID).Value
        lT2 = .Range("C" & lRowID).Value
        ltotT = .Range("D" & lRowID).Value

        Debug.Print ShowMsg(lRowID, lVSell, lT1, lT2, ltotT)
    End With
End Sub

Function ShowMsg(ByVal RowID As Integer, ByVal VSel As Long, _
ByVal T1 As Long, ByVal T2 As Long, ByVal totT As Long) As String
    Dim BaseString As String

    BaseString = "Your vehicle selection of {VEHSEL} indicates you should have " & _
                 "between {nTYRE1} and {nTYRE2} tires. However, you have entered " & _
                 "{nTotTYRE} tires for this vehicle. Please update the record " & _
                 "accordingly."

    BaseString = Replace(BaseString, "VEHSEL", VSel)
    BaseString = Replace(BaseString, "nTYRE1", T1)
    BaseString = Replace(BaseString, "nTYRE2", T2)
    BaseString = Replace(BaseString, "nTotTYRE", totT)

    ShowMsg = BaseString
End Function
```

I am assuming that the values are stored in Sheet 1 from range A5 to D5.

**EDIT**

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]
HTH

Answer (score 0):

**You could try this one**

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Variant
    x = Split("<String0>,<String1>,<String2>", ",")
    ShowMsg 23, "A", x
End Sub

Sub ShowMsg(ByVal RowID As Integer, ColID As String, Optional ByVal ReplacementValues As Variant)
    Dim nText$
    nText = Cells(RowID, ColID)
    For pos = LBound(ReplacementValues) To UBound(ReplacementValues)
        Dim searchtext$
        searchtext = "{" & CStr(pos) & "}"
        nText = Replace(nText, searchtext, ReplacementValues(pos))
    Next pos
    MsgBox nText
End Sub
```